Computing pdf of the difference of two random variables: Integrating over an indicator function that contains the variable
We want to calculate the pdf of the difference of two random variables $T_1$ and $T_2$, namely $Z=T_2-T_1$. We know the pdfs of $T_1$ and $T_2$ conditional on $T_1$ that is
$$ f_{T_1}(t_1) = b \nu e^{bt_1-\nu e^{bt_1}} $$
and
$$ f_{T_2}(t_2|T_1=t_1) = b \nu e^{\nu(e^{b t_1}-e^{b t_2})+ b t_2} 1_{[t_1,\infty]}(t_2).$$
(As for the interpretation, $T_1$ and $T_2$ describe the arrival time of a mutation in an exponentially growing population. $T_1$ is the arrival time of the first mutations. $T_2$ is the arrival time of the second mutant that must occur after $T_1$ by definition. Also, $T_1>0$ and $T_2>0$.)
Now, our question is how can we derive $f_Z(z)$ where $Z=T_2-T_1$?
Our idea was the following: We know that the sum of two random variables (say $S=X+Y$) has density $f_{S}(s)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f_{X,Y}(x,s-x) dx$ where $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ is the joint pdf. The joint distribution of $T_1$ and $T_2$ is given by
$ f_{T_1,T_2} = f_{T_1}(t_1) f_{T_2}(t_2|T_1=t_1)
= b^2 \nu^2 e^{b (t_1+t_2)-\nu e^{b t_2}} 1_{[t_1,\infty]}(t_2) $. Similarly to the pdf of the sum of two random variables, we can write the pdf of the difference between $T_1$ and $T_2$ as
$$ f_{Z}(z) = \int_0^\infty f_{T_1,T_2}(t_1,z+t_1) dt_1. $$
The problem with this approach is that solving this integral yields a solution that is still dependent on either $t_1$ or $t_2$, i.e.
$$ \int_0^\infty b^2 \nu^2 e^{b (2t_1+z)-\nu e^{b (z+t_1)}} 1_{[t_1,\infty]}(t_2) dt_1 = \int_0^{t_2} b^2 \nu^2 e^{b (2t_1+z)-\nu e^{b (z+t_1)}} dt_1 = b e^{-b z} \left(e^{\nu \left(-e^{b z}\right)} \left(\nu e^{b z}+1\right)-e^{\nu \left(-e^{b (t_2+z)}\right)} \left(\nu e^{b (t_2+z)}+1\right)\right). $$
where we used that $1_{[t_1,\infty]}(t_2)=1_{[-\infty,t_2]}(t_1)$, which becomes $1_{[0,t_2]}(t_1)$ since $t_1>0$.
In the solution, we still have two variables $z$ and $t_2$. How can we obtain a pdf for $Z$ that is independent of $T_1$ and $T_2$?

You say "we used $1_{[t_1,\infty]}(t_2)=1_{[0,t_2]}(t_1)$" though it is not obvious to me that the left expression implies $t_1\ge 0$.  Not important as you assume this for the integral

Yes, you are right. I tried to clarify this. Thanks!
